# Convert text to data in spreadsheet when copying output data from terminal?

Tags: openoffice.org

My Fortran code outputs two columns of data to the screen in a terminal. When I copy that to a spreadsheet, it always gets entered as "text" format. Is there a way to convert it to data?

I've tried many ways, including first copying it to a file, then loading the file to the spreadsheet, which fails.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

By data you probably mean "number"? Since it could be anything, like "date" or "location" or something, and since you do not provide any example of your data, I assume the following:

1. your output looks something like this:

   10 10.1

   20 20.0

   30 3000.

   40 4e1
2. You want to have it formatted as a two columns of numbers that you can e.g. sum up in the spreadsheet.

One solution could be this:

- Save the output in a file (e.g. by running your program with like this: `myprogram >> mydatafile.txt`
- Open the file with libreoffice (or openoffice). This should look like the following:

[image: LibreOffice import dialog]

Take care to select the correct separator (whatever is between your columns, here it is a space, but your program could write commas between the numbers...).

- Click on "OK" to import.
- Now your spreadsheet should look like this:

[image: Imported data]

- And you can use summation over the cells:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted. Nice answer.